# Sent SMS via Twilio failed

Tags: sms

I am using our shiny new Twilio Test account for the first time via CiviCRM and it doesn't go out.

"The From phone number +12395995225 is not a valid, SMS capable inbound phone number or short code for your account. For more information, see
[https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21606](https://www.twilio.com/doc/errors/21606)"

The receiving phone number has been verified and using API calls via Twilio site works.

What would be a good way to troubleshoot this?

Comment: hav you troubleshoot this error i facing the same problem can u help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution at the page mentioned: 
Turns out out it works with +15005550006 which means, there are still the test credtentials in the CiviCRM SMS Provider settings. Once they were replaced by the Live API information the earlier number also works.

Makes perfect sense to me.